# AEM dialog fields validation in touch UI

Tags: touch, aem, sightly

In my touch ui dialog, I  have "image path field" and text field for entering the "Alt image". Now, I want to disable the alt image field when author is not entering the image path in "image field".

any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally handled with a piece of client-side script (Javascript) that is triggered whenever the dialog is rendered/loaded or the image path field is changed.

You can find an [example Javascript here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/a37713a7e8236a7c7c2c9d10cda862144f04cc66/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v1/image/clientlibs/editor/js/decorative.click.js#L19), the relevant parts are:

```
$(document).on("coral-component:attached", ".core-image-decorative", function(e) {
    toggleInputs(e.target);
});

$(document).on("change", ".core-image-decorative", function(e) {
    toggleInputs(e.target);
});
```

This is loaded via the [following category](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/a37713a7e8236a7c7c2c9d10cda862144f04cc66/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v1/image/clientlibs/editor/.content.xml):

```
jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
categories="[core.wcm.components.image.v1.editor]"
```

The [dialog structure is here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/a37713a7e8236a7c7c2c9d10cda862144f04cc66/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v1/image/_cq_dialog/.content.xml#L6), the client library (Javascript) is loaded via:

```
sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
extraClientlibs="[core.wcm.components.image.v1.editor]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is there any way i can get the full example showing  dialog fields and where to put this JS?

Comment: @user2581831, I updated the answer to include the most relevant parts.